# A problem on rate of decay of fill distance?

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $X$ be a random variable with values in a closed compact $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^m$. Assume $\Omega$ is has a Lipschitz boundary. Let $p(x)$ be the probability density function of $X$ and assume $p(x)>0\ \forall x\in\Omega$.

Now we draw two independent sets of $n$ iid copies of $X$. We denote them $A_n = \{p_1,p_2\ldots p_n\}$ and $B_n = \{q_1,q_2\ldots q_n\}$. Consider
$$\ \ \ \ \zeta_n = \max\limits_{x\in B_n}(dist(x,A_n)) = \max\limits_{x\in B_n}\min\limits_{y\in A_n} \|x-y\|_2$$

Questions:

1. Does $\zeta_n$ converge to zero, in probability or in expectation?
2. What can we say about the rate of decay of $\zeta_n$? If we consider
   $$\gamma_n = \sup\limits_{x\in \Omega}(dist(x,A_n)) =
    \sup\limits_{x\in \Omega}\min\limits_{y\in A} \|x-y\|_2$$ instead, then I think $\gamma_n \sim  n^{-1/m}$. Can we say anything similar thing about $\zeta_n$?

Comment: Any hints or directions are also appreciated.

Comment: cross posted here:  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4118031/2987

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand\ep\varepsilon$Let $X:=\Omega$. Suppose that $|B_x(\ep)\cap X|>0$ for all $x\in X$ and all real $\ep>0$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Lebesgue measure and $B_x(\ep)$ is the open ball in $\mathbb R^m$ of radius $\ep$ centered at $x$. Then the condition $p(x)>0$ for all $x\in X$ implies that $P(p_1\in B_x(\ep)\cap X)>0$ and hence $P(p_1\notin B_x(\ep)\cap X)<1$, for all $x\in X$ and all real $\ep>0$.

On the other hand, by the compactness of $X$, for each real $\ep>0$ there is a finite set $F_\ep\subseteq X$ such that $X\subseteq\bigcup_{x\in F_\ep}B_x(\ep)$.

So, for each real $\ep>0$,
$$P(\zeta_n\ge2\ep)\le P(\gamma_n\ge2\ep)\le P\Big(\bigcup_{x\in F_\ep}\bigcap_{i=1}^k\{p_i\notin B_x(\ep)\}\Big)
\le\sum_{x\in F_\ep}P(p_1\notin B_x(\ep))^n\to0 \tag{1}$$
as $n\to\infty$.

Thus, $\gamma_n\to0$ and $\zeta_n\to0$ in probability, and hence in $L^q$ for all real $q>0$, since $\zeta_n\le\gamma_n\le D<\infty$, where $D$ is the diameter of the compact set $X$.

---

It should be straightforward to quantify this qualitative argument, in terms such as [Dudley's entropy number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudley%27s_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20probability%20theory%2C%20Dudley%27s%20theorem,its%20entropy%20and%20covariance%20structure.) and explicitly given lower bounds on $|B_x(\ep)\cap X|$ and density $p(x)$. E.g., if $p\ge c$ for some real constant $c>0$, then, by (1),
$$P(\zeta_n\ge2\ep)\le N_\ep\,(1-c|B_0(\ep)|)^n,\tag{2}$$
where $N_\ep[\le|F_\ep|]$ is the Dudley entropy number, $|F_\ep|$ is the cardinality of the set $F_\ep$, and $|B_0(\ep)|$ is the Lebesgue measure of $B_0(\ep)$.

In particular, we have $N_\ep\le(C/\ep)^m$ and $|B_0(\ep)|\le(C\ep)^m$ for some real constant $C>0$ depending only on $X$. Using now the inequality $1-u\le e^{-u}$, we see that (2) implies that $\zeta_n=O_P(n^{-1/m}\ln^{1/m}n)$.

Comment: @losifPinelis: Thank you for the answer. I have understood the inequlities on probabilities that you had mentioned. But I am not able to quantify as its not apparent to me how I can use Dudley's entropy. Sorry I am new to probability theory. Appreciate some help on how I can use Dudley's. It seems to be defined for Gaussian processes. I have no clue how I can apply.

Comment: @RajeshD : I have added details.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable answer. My expectation was the asymptotic $\zeta_n \sim n^{-1/m}$. (don't know how to formulate this in terms of probability. Can this asymptote still be derived from your answer, is what I am trying to figure out. It is already known that $\gamma_n \sim n^{-1/m}$ if I am not wrong, but I don't remember the source.

Comment: @RajeshD : You can get such a bound but only with an extra log factor, as is now detailed.

Comment: Thank you very much Losif. It is helpful.

Comment: @RajeshD : All right. So, to have a closure, does this answer look satisfactory to you?

Comment: @losif : Yes. one last thing, can we derive a lower bound as well. As I see there exist another constant  $c$  such that $N_{\epsilon}>= (c/\epsilon)^m$(as covering number is bounded from below as well). Similar is the case for $|B_0(\epsilon)|$ as $|B_0(\epsilon)|>= (c\epsilon)^m$. Appreciate your advice on the lower bound, and if its true, please add to the answer if there exists or not a lower bound.

Comment: for a lower bound, we need a different inequality on the probabilities though.

Comment: @RajeshD : Right now, I do not have good ideas about the lower bound, but I will will have this in mind.

Comment: @losif : It would be helpful if you could expand the last statement of your answer, how (2) implies the final asymptote in probability.

Comment: @RajeshD : Substitute $Kn^{-1/m}\ln^{1/m}n$ for $\varepsilon$, where $K=c^{1/m}C$. Then the upper bound in (2) will go to $0$, which implies $\zeta_n=O_P(n^{-1/m}\ln^{1/m}n)$.